# C# import excel to Datatable

Tags: c#, memory, import, xls

When passing a local path to an XLS to import to a datable, the system is giving an error where it is looking for the c:\ on the server rather than on the local machine. How can I import an XLS directly to a datable.

Comment: Is this application running through a network share or on the specific machine?

Comment: your question is not clear, how are you "importing"? what "system"?

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in a location accessible by both computers (a network share) and use that location.